# Should I be able to use the new 5.12 package version syntax without specifying the required Perl version?

Tags: perl

I am confused about the need for the `use VERSION` syntax and the `package NAME VERSION` syntax introduced in Perl 5.12. I expected to have to specify both:

```
use v5.12;

package MyPackage 0.01;
```

and any examples I have seen look like this. However, by accident (i.e. copying & pasting without paying attention) I found that this new package version syntax worked when I had `use 5.010` or even no version specified.

The underlying Perl installation is ActiveState 5.14, so in this case is the interpreter version the only requirement? I was under the impression that new features always required the `use VERSION` syntax, to assist backwards compatibility. Are there exceptions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not every new feature is a `feature`.

The `use VERSION` syntax does this:

- throw an error when the current perl version is too low.
- import the appropriate set of features from the `feature` pragma. The perldoc page of my version of `feature` lists:

  ```
  bundle    features included
  --------- -----------------
  :default  array_base

  :5.10     say state switch array_base

  :5.12     say state switch unicode_strings array_base

  :5.14     say state switch unicode_strings array_base

  :5.16     say state switch unicode_strings
             unicode_eval evalbytes current_sub fc
  ```

  (actually, `array_base` was introduced in 5.16, but was added to the previous bundles for back-compat).
- since 5.11.0, the `strict` pragma is activated in the current scope.

Some modifications are so backwards-compatible that there is no need to provide a way to deactivate them (this is what the `feature` pragma is about). The `use MODULE VERSION` syntax is largely backwards-compatible. Because of the missing comma between the version and import list in

```
use MODULE VERSION LIST;
```

this isn't an issue (i.e. this syntax was formerly illegal). When the `LIST` is missing, the `import` method would receive the version number on perls that don't recognize this syntax. The `Exporter` module handles this case, and checks the module version. So all modules that provide the `import` via Exporter (the majority) are safe.

Comment: This is a way better answer than mine.

Comment: "Not every new feature is a `feature`" - I like that, even if it shows that my original question could have been worded better!

Comment: +1 Nice table and you also got the `use strict;` info in there.

Comment: One very important item: `use :5.16` turns off the ability to change the array base by default. Thus `$[ = 1;` no longer works unless you ***turn on*** `array_base`. Bad practice of changing the array base, but this is a major change in the way Perl works and could cause programs (badly written ones) to break.

Comment: @DavidW. I'm not sure it's all that important.  How many folks are going to use the `array_base` feature in a new program or arbitrarily create a `5.16` requirement for an old one.  This is only really an issue when you decide to refactor old code, and use of `array_base` is something that should be addressed in a refactor anyway.

Comment: @tjd For 99.999% of the Perl programs, it doesn't change a thing. Something written in almost any version of Perl 5.x and even most in Perl 4.x should still work. That's because most people are bright enough to know you shouldn't modify `$[`. It was a silly feature mainly to make Perl arrays work like Awk arrays which index from 1 instead of 0. However, there are developers out there who insist on changing `$[` because they like their arrays starting at 1 and not 0. Those developers could write a program that works fine in 5.14, but fails in 5.16.

Comment: @DavidW. I must disagree with you that a program could be written that will run in 5.14 & not in 5.16.  By definition any code that includes the line `use :5.16` will fail in 5.14.  For this 'problem' to manifest a developer must 1) modify `$[` and 2) `use :5.16` specifically limiting their code to the most modern interpreters, but without the `use` you can continue to write Perl 4 compatible code on even the latest interpreters. Hmm, I'm getting pedantic.  Signing out.

Comment: @tjd So, if a developer 1). modifies `$[`, *and* uses Perl 5.16, ***but*** does not put `use :5.16;` in the program, that program will still work. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavidW. Correct, that's the point of the `feature` module and it's related 'use <version>' syntax, to grant access to new features when a program requests them but not break backwards compatibility for those that don't.

Answer (score 4):

The `use VERSION` gives you all the stuff you could turn on explicitly with `use feature`, and complain if your current version is lower than what you want. See this doc: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

> An exception is raised if VERSION is greater than the version of the
>   current Perl interpreter; Perl will not attempt to parse the rest of
>   the file.
>
> [..]
>
> `use VERSION` also enables all features available in the requested
>   version as defined by the `feature` pragma, disabling any features not
>   in the requested version's feature bundle. See feature. Similarly, if
>   the specified Perl version is greater than or equal to 5.11.0,
>   strictures are enabled lexically as with use strict . Any explicit use
>   of `use strict` or `no strict` overrides `use VERSION` , even if it comes
>   before it. In both cases, the feature.pm and strict.pm files are not
>   actually loaded.

Stuff that just changes, like behaviour of certain functions, regex modifiers and other stuff that is described in [perldelta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html) has nothing to do with this. You cannot force it to go back to behaviour of a previous version because that's not in your perl interpreter.

---

An example that occurs to me where we had this issue in production is the `/r` modifier for regular expressions. That was introduced in [Perl 5.14.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions). If you use it on 5.12 it will give a syntax error. As soon as it is run on 5.14 it will work, even with a program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $foo = 'foobar';
print $foo =~ s/foo/oof/r;
```

Comment: That's the cause of my confusion - I investigated package version syntax, and looked at the perl5120delta; I thought I understood `use VERSION`. But I should have checked the latter again because I didn't realize how `feature` worked.